# Unir variáveis e incluir 0 a um campo de 11 dígitos php

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

Estou gerando um código de barras,ele terá uma base que será da seguinte forma:

- Numero da loja:     `$v_ficha_loja = $row['ficha_loja'];`   = (1)ou (2)etc..
- Numero do ambiente: `$v_ficha_ambiente = $row['ficha_ambiente'];` (1)ou (2)etc..
- E um numero sequencial: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7, .... 100.`

Pois estou gerando um relatório e cada relatório terá seu código de barras, duvida:

Com base acima o código de barras terá 11 números,da seguinte forma:

- x1x2xxxxxx1
- x1x1xxxxxx2
- x1x2xxxxxx3
- x1x2xxxxxx4
- x1x2xxxxx10
- x1x2xxxxx11
- x1x2xxxxx12
- x1x2xxxx100

Onde coloquei `x` quero seja incluso o `0` como posso fazer isso ?

Já tenho o código do sistema e do código de barras todo pronto,só preciso gerar esse numero.

Resultado final pretendido:

> 01010000001

Comment: `0(Numero da loja)0(Numero do ambiente)0000(numero sequencial)`, seria essa a sequência de números? Os 2 primeiros zeros são mutáveis, ou *todo* `x` será sempre zero?

Comment: O que já tentaste fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caso o numero da loja e o numero do ambiente sejam SEMPRE precedidos de zero, pode-se usar `str_pad` para criar a repetição de zeros.

```
str_pad( 1   , 11 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT ) // 00000000001
str_pad( 10  , 11 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT ) // 00000000010 
str_pad( 100 , 11 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT ) // 00000000100

echo '0102' . str_pad( 100 , 11 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT ) // 010200000000100
```

---

Exemplo com `printf`

```
printf( '%s1%s2%011s' , 0 , 0 , 1   ); // 010200000000001
printf( '%s1%s2%011s' , 0 , 0 , 10  ); // 010200000000010
printf( '%s1%s2%011s' , 0 , 0 , 50  ); // 010200000000050
printf( '%s1%s2%011s' , 0 , 0 , 100 ); // 010200000000100
```

Answer (score 5):

## [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php)

O `sprintf` é uma alternativa bem prática para formatar sua *string*:

```
$barra = sprintf( "%'02d%'02d%'07d", $v_ficha_loja, $v_ficha_loja, $v_sequencia );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/yPO5jI)**.

- % para indicar substituição.
- ' para indicar qual caractere de preenchimento (por isso usamos `'0`)
- em seguida, o número de dígitos
- finalmente `d` para indicar que é um inteiro

A sintaxe é a mesma do `printf` mencionado pelo Papa Charlie, mas como você vai gerar barras, e não o valor na tela, faz mais sentido armazenar em *string*.

Mais detalhes no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php).

## [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php)

Com `str_pad` você diz qual é o valor, seguido do número de casas, do caractere de preenchimento e em qual lado ele deve ser adicionado:

```
$barra = str_pad( $v_ficha_loja    , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT )
        .str_pad( $v_ficha_ambiente, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT )
        .str_pad( $v_sequencia     , 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/QySoMc)**.

Mais detalhes no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php).

## [substr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

Esta alternativa é só pra mostrar maneiras de se trabalhar com strings em PHP. Postei mais para ilustrar e pensar fora da caixa:

```
    $barra = substr(      '00'.$v_ficha_loja    , -2 )
            .substr(      '00'.$v_ficha_ambiente, -2 )
            .substr( '0000000'.$v_sequencia     , -7 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/mKh8rg)**.

Mais detalhes no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php).